# Does child pom inherit plugins from parent pom

Tags: maven, inheritance, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

In a multi module maven project, does a child pom inherits plugins defined in parent pom?

Maven documentation around the plugin inheritance is a bit confusing to me. According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins)

> If your POM declares a parent, it inherits plugin **configuration** from
> either the build/plugins or pluginManagement sections of the parent.

So I'm assuming only the configuration will be inherited in case if the child has the same plugin defined under `<build><plugins>` section. If child does not have the plugin then it's not inherited from the parent.

Can someone please confirm if this is the correct understanding, or I'm missing anything here.

Answer (score 1):

You inherit everything, so your understanding is incorrect.